# (VB.NET)Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement - MICROSOFT JET DATABASE ENGINE

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need help, I developed a simple Access database and I create a VB .Net user interface.
I can't INSERT data into the Table here's my sample code... I'm only a beginner in VB.Net i hope you could help me with this one

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As DataRow


    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\Documents and Settings\Test\Desktop\Privilege.Net\PrivilegeCard\Database\dbPrivilegeSystem.mdb"

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From tblUsers;"

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "tblUsers")

        dr = ds.Tables("tblUsers").NewRow


        'System.Convert.ToDateTime(dtPicker.Value).ToOADate()
        'I've been trying to use this conversion for date thinking if this could help me fix my problem

        dr(0) = txtUserN.Text
        dr(1) = txtPass.Text
        dr(2) = txtAccess.Text
        dr(3) = dtPicker.Value
        dr(4) = txtName.Text
        dr(5) = txtPos.Text
        dr(6) = cmbDept.Text

        ds.Tables("tblUsers").Rows().Add(dr)

        Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Update(ds, "tblUsers")

    Catch ex As OleDbException

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
    End Try
```

Comment: My table attributes are UserName,PassWord,AccessLevel,DateCreated,Name,Position,Department

they are all in a Text data type except the DateCreated which is in a Date/Time data type

Answer (score 1):

take a look at my code ,it is easer

```
Imports System.Data
Partial Class theClassName
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Ole DB Services=-4; Data Source=" & MapPath("~/App_Data") & "/database.mdb"
        Dim dbconnection As System.Data.IDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim queryString As String = "Insert into [customer] ([ID],[name],[address],[phone],[date_of_birth],[Nationality],[room_no],[number_of_days]) Values (" & txtid.Text & ", '" & txtname.Text & "', '" & txtaddress.Text & "', " & txtphone.Text & ", " & txtdate.Text & ", '" & txtnation.Text & "'," & txtroom.Text & "," & txtday.Text & ")"
        Dim dbcommand As System.Data.IDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
        dbcommand.CommandText = queryString
        dbcommand.Connection = dbconnection
        dbconnection.Open()
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        Try
            rowsAffected = dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery
            result.Text = "Record Saved"
        Catch
            result.Text = "Record not saved"
        Finally
            dbconnection.Close()
        End Try

           End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: +1 but should explain more. To the OP, you don't want to select an entire table of results just to add one record. This is a hold-over from "stupid things to do in VB6 and MS Access" from years gone by; we've all written our first apps like this because of the plethora of horrible examples. However, tend to think in terms of "Select to get data" (using DataSet or DataTable or whatever), "Commands to Insert, Update, and Delete".

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours on this yesterday and was getting the unexplained syntax error as well. If you do still want to use the DataAdapter and CommandBuilder then try adapting the following to suit your database. First though, it's a good idea and may be mandatory for this to work, to create a unique/auto numeric ID column. Also, change your PassWord field name to something that won't risk a keyword clash. Finally, I read somewhere that field names with spaces may not work under these circumstances either.
This works for me, hope it works for you! (And you get your date working.)

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\Client.mdb"

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Client;"

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        da.Fill(ds, "Client")
        dr = ds.Tables("Client").NewRow()

        'System.Convert.ToDateTime(dtPicker.Value).ToOADate()
        'I've been trying to use this conversion for date thinking if this could help me fix my problem

        'dr(0) = Auto Index. Don't update.
        dr(1) = "updated"
        dr(2) = 345
        ds.Tables("Client").Rows.Add(dr)
        da.Update(ds, "Client")
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response...
There is no error in your codes above but you still get error in INSERT INTO statement because MS Access **strictly used keywords** like password, timestamp, user, position; to avoid error change fields into userpassword or userpwd or anything that is unique fields.

Thank you...