# Visual Studio 2010 insert syntax error again and again while inserting value to .mdb file

Tags: vb.net

what is missing in insert statement ? the full code is now here. i cant add new fields values to .mdb file. it took 3 days to develop this app and now its not running.

what is missing in insert statement ? the full code is now here. i cant add new fields values to .mdb file. it took 3 days to develop this app and now its not running.

```
Public Class client
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub reloaddata()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from clientsData", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.cview.DataSource = dt
    cnn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    display.Hide()
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\clients.mdb"
    Me.reloaddata()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    display.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub cview_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles cview.CellClick

    If cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cnn.Open()

    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    i = cview.CurrentRow.Index
    If cview.CurrentCell.Value Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Empty Field")
    Else
        view.lbl1.Text = cview.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl2.Text = cview.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl3.Text = cview.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl4.Text = cview.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl5.Text = cview.Item(4, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl6.Text = cview.Item(5, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl7.Text = cview.Item(6, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl8.Text = cview.Item(11, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl9.Text = cview.Item(12, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl10.Text = cview.Item(7, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl11.Text = cview.Item(8, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl12.Text = cview.Item(9, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl13.Text = cview.Item(10, i).Value.ToString
        view.lbl14.Text = cview.Item(13, i).Value.ToString
        view.Show()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
      cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn       
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into clientsdata(ID,Client,Project,Domain,Hosting,bulk sms,maintenance,Order date,amount,last billing,next billing,username,password,due amount) VALUES ('" & Me.cid.Text & "','" & Me.cname.Text & "','" & Me.cproj.Text & "','" & Me.cdmn.Text & "','" & Me.chost.Text & "','" & Me.csms.Text & "','" & Me.cmain.Text & "','" & Me.codt.Text & "','" & Me.camnt.Text & "','" & Me.cldt.Text & "','" & Me.cndt.Text & "','" & Me.cuid.Text & "','" & Me.cpass.Text & "','" & Me.cdue.Text & "' )"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Me.reloaddata()
   cnn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    cid.Text = "cid"
    cname.Text = "cname"
    cproj.Text = "cpro"
    cdmn.Text = "domain"
    chost.Text = "chost"
    csms.Text = "sms"
    cmain.Text = "main"
    codt.Text = "codt"
    camnt.Text = "mount"
    cldt.Text = "last"
    cndt.Text = "next"
    cdue.Text = "due"
    cuid.Text = "uid"
    cpass.Text = "pass"
   End Sub
```

End Class

ok problem solved !! I just added [ ] in the fields.

source: [(VB.NET)Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement - MICROSOFT JET DATABASE ENGINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898707/vb-netsyntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-microsoft-jet-database-engine?rq=1)

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into clientsdata([ID],[Client],[Project],[Domain],[Hosting],[bulk sms],[maintenance],[Order date],[amount],[last billing],[next billing],[username],[password],[due amount]) VALUES (" & Me.cid.Text & ",'" & Me.cname.Text & "','" & Me.cproj.Text & "','" & Me.cdmn.Text & "','" & Me.chost.Text & "','" & Me.csms.Text & "','" & Me.cmain.Text & "','" & Me.codt.Text & "','" & Me.camnt.Text & "','" & Me.cldt.Text & "','" & Me.cndt.Text & "','" & Me.cuid.Text & "','" & Me.cpass.Text & "','" & Me.cdue.Text & "' )"
```

Comment: new connection,provider etc already added in form1_load section

Comment: Your not disposing  the command and the SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection, pooling connection objects but not connections which take most of the overhead, no point in opening the connection until after youve detirmined wheather to do the query...

Comment: what kind of format in codt.Text, cldt.Text, cndt.Text ?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date` field is a keyword.  You have to place it with brackets: `[date]`.  Also, any field names that have spaces require brackets, too:  `[Order date]`.

You really should use parameters to avoid SQL injection and to solve a host of other issues with updating databases.

I would also avoid trying to manage the connection state of the database.  Just use the `Using` syntax so that the connection always closes.

```
If Me.cid.Text = "" Then
  MessageBox.Show("Please input values")
Else
  Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("...")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
      cmd.Connection = con
      cmd.CommandText = "..."
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.cid.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...more)
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
  End Using

  reloaddata()
End If
```

Comment: i have rebuilt the database and changed date to order date.. but problem still occurs "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: @Ravikant If you aren't going to use parameters, you will have to get your single quotation marks correct.  I see one missing in the very beginning: `VALUES(" & Me.cid.Text & ",'"` should be `VALUES('" & Me.cid.Text & "','"`.

Comment: @Ravikant You have to put brackets [] around field names that have spaces: `[order date]`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing what is contained in each of the `.Text` values, and without seeing the definition of the table you are filling in. But I could hazard a guess that the `Me.camnt.Text` and `Me.cdue.Text` probably don't want to be surrounded by single quotes; that is to say, you may need something like this...

```
Me.codt.Text & "'," & Me.camnt.Text & ",'" & Me.cldt.Text
```

and

```
Me.cndt.Text & "'," & Me.cdue.Text & ",'" & Me.cuid.Text
```

Comment: me.camnt.text contains the value to be inserted in mdb file.

Comment: @Ravikant, yes, I appreciate that. The point is that if they are numbers, and the column being filled in is a numeric column, quote marks are not required.